# How to show insert query generated through $model->save() function

Tags: yii

I want to show the query which is generated when we call the function $model->save() of a model.
I did not find any way to do it.
If anyone knows please reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your 'db' component in your config file -

```
'db'=>array(
         …
        'enableProfiling'=>true,
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
),
```

Then check wherever you are logging everything. If file, it will be application.log file. Else on the page itself. To enable logging in file -

```
    'log'=>array(
      'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',                    
                'levels'=>'trace, info, error, warning',
        ),
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',  
                // 'categories' => 'system.db.*',
                'levels'=>'trace, info, error, warning',    
            ),

        ),
```

Comment: +1, will definitely work, but isn't there any in built function, that can be used?

Comment: You should remember to disable profiling, if you copied this in your config, when going from development to production.