# Yii Get MySql query executed

Tags: php, mysql, logging, yii

I need get the MySql query executed before Save, Update, Delete for create a personal LOG (audit).

I use $model->save() and $model->delete() standard from CActiveRecord.

Any know how i can do this?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the methods

```
class Objects extends CActiveRecord

{

 protected function beforeSave()

    {
      // Your code goes here

    }


 protected function beforeDelete()

    {
      // Your code goes here

    }

}
```

For Logging of query you refer this thread [Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598179/how-to-show-insert-query-generated-through-model-save-function)

u can also see the log on the page by just uncommenting the follwing code in config.main  file

```
// uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages

                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
```

Comment: Yes, i know it, but my question is:
How i can get the SQL Query executed?

Comment: what is the query that u want to execute ??

Comment: i want get the query executed. Ex:
I do $model->save();
I want have a log of the "save" query executed. Ex:
INSERT INTO user VALUES('xx');

I need this sql query.

Comment: I mean u want the details of the query ?? please clear your question i am bit confused

Comment: yes yes, i need the details of the query.
Because if i do $model->save() i don't know which is the executed statement, and i need write the sentence in a audit table (All insert and delete executed querys.)

Comment: Already knew this component.
But this only prints out SQL statements. then
How do you pick these SQL statements to store in the audit table?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: For that you refer http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/9/how-to-log-changes-of-activerecords/