# How to get last executed query Yii

Tags: yii

How to get Last executed query after  model save, update, delete in yii.

i.e:

```
$model->save();
```

like $this->db->last_query(); in CI

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442470/yii-get-mysql-query-executed)

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your config.php file , you can see other details along with your query ...

```
'db'=>array(
    'enableProfiling'=>true,
    'enableParamLogging' => true,
 ),

 'log'=>array(
 'class'=>'CLogRouter',
 'routes'=>array(
    …
    array(
        'class'=>'CProfileLogRoute',
        'levels'=>'profile',
        'enabled'=>true,
    ),
  ),
 ),
```

Comment: You should remember to disable profiling, if you copied this in your config, when going from development to production.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to show last executed query is to make an sql error in that query! :p Give an invalid column name in query, then Yii error reporting will show that query as error, but you can see that query.

Comment: You were downvoted, and with reason because this is not the ideal way to do it, BUT that's how I do it because is the easiest way to see the executed query :D